# Generate source code from text file

Tags: java, file

Say I have a text file with a simple method:

```
public void sayHello() {
    System.out.println("HELLO!");
}
```

Is there anyway to take that code and programatically insert the code into an existing .java file? Or even create a new Java source file with the code provided in the text file? I have heard of solutions where you can generate source code using [CodeModel](https://codemodel.java.net/), but I would have to write my own parser to handle all the possible code that would be read from the text file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run a simple text file as Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226063/run-a-simple-text-file-as-java)

Comment: Not sure to understand. You want a #include equivalent?

Comment: @johand. That doesn't even make sense. This is Java, not C++.

Comment: Yeah I understand. That why I wrote "equivalent".

Comment: Hit like if you got it here-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374758/how-can-i-execute-java-code-retrived-from-txt-file?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here: [How do I programmatically compile and instantiate a Java class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946338/how-do-i-programmatically-compile-and-instantiate-a-java-class)

You can use the [javax.tools](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html) to compile the code and then load it into your JVM.

Oracle has a [write-up](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) as does [IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jcomp/).